# Can a hacker potentially take down 90% of the top ten websites hacking into Markmonitor?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-registrar

90% of the top 10 websites, Facebook, Google, Yahoo, Youtube, etc register their Domain Names with a domain registrar called MarkMonitor. If Markmonitor were hacked, the hacker could reset the name servers and effectively make them inaccessible or direct traffic to a phishing website.

Source & Other Info:
http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2013/a-single-kill-switch-for-90-of-the-top-ten-websites/

- Is this a potential risk?
- What security restrictions could Mark Monitor have in place to prevent changes?
- Is it too costly for these companies to be a registrar themselves (like IBM)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a potential risk?

No.  You are ignoring DNS propagation times.

> What security restrictions could $provider have in place to prevent changes?

The usual to not get hacked. Nothing special here.

> Is it too costly for these companies to be a registrar themselves (like IBM)

It is not their core business.